# Redirect from _Layout.cshtml to homepage on page load

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to load to my homepage when I start, so that the _Layout page doesn't show and my website starts at the homepage. I have tried to redirect the page to the homepage but due to it being a template for the other pages it is in a constant loop of redirects.

```
@{ Context.Response.Redirect("/Homepage");}
```

How can I fix my issue and be able to go to my homepage while skipping the _layout page when I start the server.

Comment: I think there may be some terminology issues. _Layout, as you said, is a template and not a page. If you want a page not using that template to load, you can make your default page not use that template. You don't "skip" a template, but you can choose to not use it. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yeah some terminology is bit wrong , to better specify is that the Index page loads first and everything on that _Layout template is on the Index page but , the template expands over all the other razor pages , but I want to skip the index page and go directly to the homepage when I start the server.

Comment: I think I see what you want to do, would you like to have the default or "homepage" be a different controller/action than the default "HomeController" with the action "Index"? You should be able to change that easily in startup if you like.

Comment: Yes, I made a new page named Homepage, that I want to be the new default when I start the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to have a different page by default you have set your routes in the startup to have a default

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

And you can change the pattern for the controller and action there that would load by default if those parameters are missing. Note this will work only if not other routing options are present, either attribute routing or something else.

So perhaps you want something like this depending on the controller?

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Homepage}/{id?}");
```

Edit:

If you are using razor pages, it can get trickier and the simpliest solution is to just use attribute routing.

At the top of the page you want to be the default, put

```
@page "/"
```

And for the previous default page put whatever you like, something like

```
@page "/NotDefaultAnymore"
```

Or whatever you would like the route to be.

Comment: app.MapControllerRoute isn't present in my program.cs file and when I insert that piece of code it does nothing, am I missing something?

Comment: This would be in startup.cs most likely. Can you share what you have in your configure function there?

Comment: var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();

Comment: That is what is in my program.cs file, sorry for the bad formatting, still new here.

Comment: Oh gosh, this might be totally my bad. I was thinking you were using MVC instead of Razor. If you are using Razor pages then routing gets trickier (in my opinion). The simplest thing to do is just rename what you want to be the default page as Index.cshtml assuming you have a flat folder structure. You can also change the default folders it looks at if the folder structure is more complex. Can you share the filenames and directories for these two pages?

Comment: I added an update to my answer to use attribute routing for razor pages. This might be your simplest solution for now.

Comment: /pages/shared/_Layout.cshtml   is the default page and /pages/Homepage.cshtml is my new razor page I made that I want to set as my default.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243589/discussion-between-ben-matthews-and-pieter-venter).